# Resource not found exception using kinesis spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use spark structured streaming with kinesis. Following is my code.

```
val kinesis = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kinesis")
      .option("streams", streamName)
      .option("region", "us-east-1")
      .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
      .option("endpointUrl", "kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
      .option("awsAccessKey", accessKey)
      .option("awsSecretKey", secretKey)
      .option("format", "json")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .schema(schema)
      .load
val query = kinesis.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()
    query.awaitTermination()
```

I also exported accesskey and secret key as environment variables. But when I execute it. I have following exception

```
ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 45b3e45a-6a3b-48c6-9183-8531f85ea537, runId = ab5bbfd6-d9f7-455c-8065-fa65de932914] terminated with error
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Stream dev-rt-stream-ds-5 under account 438156723281 not found. (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: f1b1384c-2528-e50f-a358-2e59f9ad3b45)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
```

Following code returns correct number of shards.

```
val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
val kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials)
kinesisClient.setEndpoint("kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
val numShards = kinesisClient.describeStream(streamName).getStreamDescription().getShards().size
println("num shards => " + numShards)
```

Comment: Which connector are you using? This one: https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql?